# How to get a list of attribute values from checked checkboxes of a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have some mark up like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="fieldapprovalcheckbox" data-invoicelineid=3 />
<input type="checkbox" class="fieldapprovalcheckbox" data-invoicelineid=4 />
<input type="checkbox" class="fieldapprovalcheckbox" data-invoicelineid=5 />
```

Now say all these checkboxes have been checked in jquery how would I get a list of all the data-invoicelineid? ie. It should contain 3,4,5.

I wrote the following but it only gets the first one.

```
var checkedInvoiceLineIds = $(".fieldeapprovalcheckbox:checked").attr("data-invoicelineid");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var checkedInvoiceLineIds = [];
$(".fieldeapprovalcheckbox:checked").each(function(){
   checkedInvoiceLineIds.push($(this).data("invoicelineid"));
});
```

Answer (score 6):

you should use map()

```
var checkedInvoiceLineIds = $(".fieldeapprovalcheckbox:checked").map(function(){
        return $(this).data("invoicelineid");
}).get();
```

and you hav an array that contains the checked values

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the `is checked` test because the selector already only matches checked items, right?

Comment: @keegan3d yes yes i removed that! :)